# Javascript focus not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, html

This code works fine in <= IE7, but it doesn't work in firefox .. i am using firefox browser 12.0 .. I am not sure whats the reason .. help would be much appreciated .. thanks ..

```
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
   function getfocus(obj){
      if(obj.value.length==0){
        alert("Please enter something");
        obj.focus();
      }
   }
 </script>
</head>

<body>
   <input type="text" onblur="getfocus(this)" value="Get focus">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: what exactly happens on Firefox? What are you expecting?

Comment: What part isn't working? Where does it break/stop? Any errors in your JavaScript console?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try:

```
....
alert("Please enter something");
setTimeout(function() {
    obj.focus()
}, 10);
```

Comment: Is there a rational explanation with facts (source) that tells us why the focus isn't triggered when an alert is shown beforehand? This works, but I'm just curious.

Answer (score 1):

Some browsers, notably Firefox, have user-specific settings which control whether focus may be 'stolen' from the user. I think this may be your problem here.

However, you might want to re-consider your tactics here for ensuring the user enters some text. Having an alert pop-up every time you unfocus a blank text field would be *extremely* irritating to most users.

Answer (score 0):

The code is working fine to me both on FF 12 and Chrome.
You need to clear the input filed and then get out of the item in order to see the alert...

Comment: It is NOT working inside jsfiddle - but as single html page - it does!